# Is there an easy way to get all common module extensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, file-extension

I am making a library that deals with Python modules.  Without getting into details, I need a list of the common Python module extensions.

Obviously, I want `.py`, but I'd also like to include ones such as `.pyw`, `.pyd`, etc.  In other words, I want anything that you can import.

Is there a tool in the standard library which will make this list for me?  Or do I have to make it myself (and hardcode all of the values)?

```
extensions = ['.py', '.pyw', ...]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This functionality can be found in the [`importlib.machinery` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.machinery). Inside, there are numerous constants which relate to the various Python module extensions:

```
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.machinery.SOURCE_SUFFIXES
['.py', '.pyw']
>>> importlib.machinery.OPTIMIZED_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES
['.pyo']
>>> importlib.machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
['.pyd']
>>> importlib.machinery.DEBUG_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES
['.pyc']
>>>
```

So, you could very easily join these into a global set<sup>1</sup>:

```
>>> set(importlib.machinery.SOURCE_SUFFIXES +
...     importlib.machinery.OPTIMIZED_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES +
...     importlib.machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES +
...     importlib.machinery.DEBUG_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES)
{'.pyw', '.py', '.pyd', '.pyc', '.pyo'}
>>>
```

---

You might also be interested in the [`all_suffixes` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.all_suffixes):

```
>>> importlib.machinery.all_suffixes()
['.py', '.pyw', '.pyc', '.pyd']
>>>
```

Note however that this function will replace `.pyc` with `.pyo` if Python is launched with either the [`-O` or `-OO` options](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#miscellaneous-options).  To avoid this, you can do:

```
>>> set(importlib.machinery.all_suffixes() +
...     importlib.machinery.OPTIMIZED_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES +
...     importlib.machinery.DEBUG_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES)
{'.pyw', '.py', '.pyd', '.pyc', '.pyo'}
>>>
```

This will ensure that both `.pyc` and `.pyo` are in the set.

---

Finally, you should be wary of `importlib.machinery.BYTECODE_SUFFIXES`.  As @MartijnPieters noted in the comments, it will always be equal to either `OPTIMIZED_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES` or `DEBUG_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES`.  This means that if you add it to the collection, you will get either a duplicated `.pyc` or a duplicated `.pyo` value (unless you use a set of course).

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.BYTECODE_SUFFIXES):

> `importlib.machinery.BYTECODE_SUFFIXES`
>
> A list of strings representing the recognized file suffixes for bytecode modules. Set to either `DEBUG_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES` or
>   `OPTIMIZED_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES` based on whether `__debug__` is true.

I didn't bother using this constant however because I want both `OPTIMIZED_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES` and `DEBUG_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES` in the collection.  So, there is no reason to add it.

---

<sup>1</sup>I decided to use a set because they have a faster lookup time than lists.  Meaning, they are better suited for a global collection of values that will not change and which needs no particular order.  In addition, they will ensure that we do not accidentally add duplicate extensions to the collection.

Comment: Note that `all_suffixes()` also includes *extension modules*; on Mac this gives `['.py', '.pyc', '.cpython-34m.so', '.abi3.so', '.so']` for example.

Comment: Also, append either `importlib.machinery.OPTIMIZED_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES` or `importlib.machinery.DEBUG_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES`, which ever is *not* equal to `importlib.machinery.BYTECODE_SUFFIXES`. Otherwise you'll have `.pyo` *twice* when running with `-O` or `-OO`.

Comment: Yes, a set would be better still. See the [`importlib.machinery.BYTECODE_SUFFIXES`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.BYTECODE_SUFFIXES`) documentation: *Set to either `DEBUG_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES` or `OPTIMIZED_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES` based on whether `__debug__` is true.*